# How to override header set in Apache config with more specific header in a virtual host

Tags: php, apache, http-headers, apache2, virtualhost

I have a header set in the main Apache (2.4.41 Ubuntu) config with a general CSP:

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self';"
```

I'm trying to override this for a specific website, in its virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName example.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/example/app
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/default.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/private/default.key

        Header always set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors https://example2.com https://example3.com;"

</VirtualHost>
```

The virtual host header is ignored though. The HTTP response still returns the original header from the Apache config.

---

As an alternative, I tested overriding the header via the PHP app itself, but it simply adds a second duplicate header and the original Apache one still prevails.

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self';
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors https://example2.com https://example3.com;
```

Comment: I have this question - on a server with multiple vhosts I'd like to set frame-ancestors to none in /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf and then override at the vhost level, but those hosts then end up with two headers, browsers (Firefox at least) honouring the stricter one

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I think I figured this out. I do:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'none';"
```

in /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf (Apache on Ubuntu 18.04), and then in my virtual host do this:

```
Header unset Content-Security-Policy
Header always append Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' https://*.mydomain.com;"
```

This seems to work. My understanding is that this will remove any previously set Content-Security-Policy headers.